# Customize Native Base tabs

Tags: javascript, ios, css, react-native

I'm just started learning about React Native.

Now I need help to customize my tabs. I'm using advanced tabs by Native Base.

I want to change this :

[image]

to be like this :

[image]

I've checked on the native base documentation for styling the tabs, but I dont know where to put these properties:
[image]

Here some of my code:

```js
<Container>
                    <Header
                        style={styles.headerColor}
                        iosBarStyle='light-content'
                    >
                        <Left>
                            <Button transparent onPress={()=>this.openDrawer()}>
                                <Icon name='ios-menu' style={styles.icons}/>
                            </Button>
                            </Left>
                        <Body>
                            <Title style={styles.headerTitle}>INQUIRY LIST</Title>
                        </Body>
                        <Right>
                            <Button transparent>
                                <Icon name='ios-search' style={styles.icons}/>
                            </Button>
                        </Right>
                    </Header>
                    <Tabs activeTabStyle={{borderBottomColor: '#fff'}}>
                        <Tab heading={ <TabHeading><Text style={styles.tabsText}>ALL</Text></TabHeading>}>
                            {/* <Tab1 /> */}
                        </Tab>
                        <Tab heading={ <TabHeading><Text style={styles.tabsText}>NEW</Text></TabHeading>}>
                            {/* <Tab2 /> */}
                        </Tab>
                        <Tab heading={ <TabHeading><Text style={styles.tabsText}>RECEIVED</Text></TabHeading>}>
                            {/* <Tab3 /> */}
                        </Tab>
                        <Tab heading={ <TabHeading><Text style={styles.tabsText}>IN PROGRESS</Text></TabHeading>}>
                            {/* <Tab3 /> */}
                        </Tab>
                        <Tab heading={ <TabHeading><Text style={styles.tabsText}>COMPLETED</Text></TabHeading>}>
                            {/* <Tab3 /> */}
                        </Tab>
                    </Tabs>
                    <Text>Hi from Inquiries</Text>
                </Container>
```

```css
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    tabsText:{
      fontSize: 10
    },
    headerColor:{
      backgroundColor: '#1b1b1b'
    },
    activeTab:{
      borderBottomColor: '#fff'
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how i designed my tabs. Change the styling as needed.

```
<Tabs tabBarUnderlineStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#f9ec97' }}>
                    <Tab heading="Description" activeTextStyle={{ color: '#fff', fontWeight: 'bold' }} textStyle={{ color: '#fff', fontSize: 12 }} tabStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#2f2483' }} activeTabStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#2f2483' }} >
                        {/* <Tab1 /> */}
                    </Tab>
.....
                </Tabs>
```

you need to specify styles for every tab.

Comment: This does NOT work. This will style the individual tabs but not the area around them.

Comment: how to put icons ?

Answer (score -2):

In opening Tabs remove `<ScrollableTab />` customize you own

```
  <Tabs
    onChangeTab
    ref={(ref) => this.tabref = ref}
    renderTabBar={() => (
      <View style={{
        backgroundColor:"yellow",
        flexDirection:"row",
        justifyContent:"center"
      }}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          activeOpacity={1}
          onPress={() => this.tabref.goToPage(0)}
          activeTabStyle={{backgroundColor:"yellow"}}
          style={{
            backgroundColor:"red",
            width:width * 0.50,
            height:50,
            justifyContent:"center",
            alignItems:"center"
          }}>
          <Text>Sign In</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          activeOpacity={1}
          onPress={() => this.tabref.goToPage(1)}
          style={{
            backgroundColor:"green",
            width:width * 0.50,
            height:50,
            justifyContent:"center",
            alignItems:"center"
          }}>
          <Text>Sign Up</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    }
  >
```

Comment: Why the downvotes? This actually works better than the accepted answer. Tabs "renderTabBar" allows you to replace the default tab bar with a custom one.